# Help w/ remote update sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have written code that remotely updates a sqlite database in my iPhone app. After the new database has been downloaded and saved, it replaces the old one using **[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:DBPath]** and **[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:newDBTempPath to:DBPath]**. All these operations go smoothly.

However, when I open the new database afterwards, without closing the app, and run a query, I sometimes get only 1 result (the first out of the 807 I expect) and sometimes none. The query runs without any errors though. <strike>Then, when I close (shutdown) the app, and re-open, the same query gives me back my 807 results</strike>. This happens both on the simulator as well as on a real-life iPhone.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** Had an error in my programming. Now when I open the newly copied database in Navicat, I get an error, so something goes wrong while downloading.

**UPDATE 2:** Fixed! To save memory, I wrote every downloaded 100KB chunk to the file, but forgot to write the last chunk when NSURLConnection was finished. This lead to an incomplete file, DOH!

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your app has the database closed when you replace it? If you touch the file while it's open you'll confuse it, probably terminally. This goes double if the journal was open at the time (this is the file that will appear periodically next to the database file).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Am pretty sure the database is closed, the process to update the file takes place in the first (and only) viewcontroller that is loaded. Only after updating can the user select to load a second viewcontroller that then uses the DB.
Also, everything is fine if the app is closed and re-opened